# Importing Pandas Data Reader

Tags: python, python3, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to get Pandas DataReader on Juptyer, but it is not working! I went to the Anaconda Prompt, and typed

```
pip install pandas-datareader
```

which it ran successfully. I then went to my jupyter notebook and typed

```
import pandas datareader as pdr
```

I got a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have tried everything that I can think of, but it keeps giving me that error. I could really use some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) say, it's `pandas_datareader` *not* `pandas datareader`